# How do I make duplicate fragments get their individual layoutid?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to make an ultimate TicTacToe game, which requires running 9 instances of the same fragment at the same time. I house them Inside another fragment that'll control each. While performing other tasks.

I am trying to figure out a way to manage each fragment, have them talk to each other, and know who they are. (basically store its row and col and maybe allow the big layout run some methods) Is there a way to do that? I don't have much experience with fragment managers, but I'm not swapping anything out and It would seem like a lot of work for such a simple task.

Big Fragment

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_Big_Row_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/board_0x0"
            android:name="com.example.tictactectoe.Fragment_Small_Board"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/board_0x1"
            android:name="com.example.tictactectoe.Fragment_Small_Board"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        ....
    <LinearLayout/>
    ....
  <LinearLayout/>
```

smallFragment.java

```
public class Fragment_Small_Board extends Fragment {

    private int thisRow = 0;
    private int thisCol = 0;

    private ImageButton square0x0;
    private ImageButton square0x1;
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_board, container, false);

        setUpButtons(view);
        buttonOnclickListeners();

        return view;
    }

    public void setUpButtons(View view){
       square0x0 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.small_0_0);
       square0x1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.small_0_1);
       ....
    }

    public void buttonOnclickListeners(){
        square0x0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validateMove();
                square0x0.setBackgroundResource(backgroundID);
                square0x0.setImageResource(pictureID);
            }
        });
       ....
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `Fragment`s for this? I mean, it doesn't really seem like you're doing anything that can't be done more easily with regular `View`s.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put 9 fragments inside parent fragment because in your case, it doesn't look necessary. So what you can do is add these nine fragments inside your activity.and provide each fragment with communicator(interface) so that they can communicate via activity to each other.

To add fragments do something like this

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragment =new MyFragment();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
    ft.commit();
```

and according to your functionalities keep on replacing fragments .

[This link will give you brief idea about how to set up communicator inside fragment and extend it in your activity](http://techblogon.com/communication-between-activity-and-fragment-example/)